# Create SQLite 3 table with foreign key constraint via ActiveRecord migration

Tags: activerecord, sqlite, foreign-keys, rails-migrations

Unlike MySQL and Postgres, SQLite doesn't support adding foreign key constraints to an existing table. One therefore can't create a foreign key constraint with `add_foreign_key` in an ActiveRecord migration.

However, as of 3.6.19, SQLite [it does support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) including foreign key constraints in the CREATE TABLE statement, and it [is possible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references) to specify `foreign_key: true` when defining a `reference` column in a `create_table` migration:

```
class CreateChildren < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :children do |t|
      t.text :name
      t.references :parent, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I look at the generated `schema.rb`, this appears to be ignored:

```
create_table "children", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text    "name"
  t.integer "parent_id"
end
```

Is there a technical reason this is impossible, or is it just a missing feature? Is there a workaround?